# IncludeMembers of Automapper not works as expected

Tags: automapper, automapper-10

According to automapper [docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/v10.0.0/Flattening.html#includemembers), I can map nested objects to destination using IncludeMembers function. I have issues with next [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ALUj1U).

Code is available on net fiddle, below is quick reference:

How I map:

```
    var source = new CategoryStatus
    {
        Subgroup = new CategorySubgroup
        {
            SubgroupCode = "SubgroupCode",
            CategoryGroup = new CategoryGroup { GroupCode = "SubgroupCode" }
        }
    };
    
    var result = Mapper.Map<Dest, CategoryStatus>(source);
```

My classes:

```
public class Dest
{
    public string SubgroupCode { get; set; }
    public string GroupCode { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryStatus
{
    public CategorySubgroup Subgroup { get; set; }
}

public class CategorySubgroup
{
    public string SubgroupCode { get; set; }
    public CategoryGroup CategoryGroup { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryGroup
{
    public string GroupCode { get; set; }
}
```

My Configuration:

```
var cfg2 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {

        cfg.CreateMap<CategoryStatus, Dest>()
            .IncludeMembers(x => x.Subgroup);

        cfg.CreateMap<CategoryGroup, Dest>();

        cfg.CreateMap<CategorySubgroup, Dest>()
            .IncludeMembers(x => x.CategoryGroup);

    });
```

Error:

> [System.ArgumentException: Property 'System.String GroupCode' is not defined for type 'CategorySubgroup']

Any ideas about configuration setup? Automapper version is 10.0.0

**Update**

Version 9.0.0 works. Possible latest will also work, but it contains some breaking changes for me, so I didn't test it.

Comment: I think there is an issue on apply IncludeMembers for `cfg.CreateMap<CategoryStatus, Dest>()`. This may not the answer you looking for, I use `AfterMap` as an alternative, [sample demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iY7s7T).

Comment: Upgrade AM to the latest.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu version 9.00 works fine. Possible latest will work, but it breaks current code

Comment: Surely it's not that hard to upgrade :) But I guess 9 works too.